# iPhoto treats two identical video cameras in totally different ways

Tags: video, photos.app, camera, quicktime

I own two Canon Vixia HF G20 video cameras.  The two cameras are, as far as I can tell, configured in completely identical ways.  And yet for some reason when I connect them to my Mac to import video, completely different things happen:

- When I connect one of the cameras, iPhoto launches automatically, the camera appears under "Devices" in the iPhoto sidebar, and I have the option to import video directly into my iPhoto library.
- When I connect the other camera, iPhoto does not launch automatically. If I launch it manually, the camera does not appear under "Devices", and there does not seem to be any way to get iPhoto to recognize that the camera is connected, or to import video from it.  Instead I have to navigate to the AVCHD file in the Finder, open video clips using Quicktime Player, and then use Quicktime Player to Save the clips to my hard drive.  (This method works on the other camera, too, of course.)

Since I am able to save video from both cameras to my HD, this difference in behavior is not mission-critical, but it is annoying and mysterious.  I am not sure if the difference has to do with a setting in iPhoto, or on the camera itself, or what.  Can anybody explain to me why these two cameras -- same model, same configuration (AFAIK) -- are handled by the OS so differently?

**Edited to add:**
User tubedogg asked:

> When it's connected, go to Apple menu > About > System Report button. What does the USB bus report for the port where it is plugged in?

So here is what shows up for Camera 1 (the one that is recognized by iPhoto and Image Capture):

```
    Video Camera:

  Product ID:   0x326e
  Vendor ID:    0x04a9  (Canon Inc.)
  Version:  0.01
  Serial Number:    [redacted]
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: CANON Inc.
  Location ID:  0x1d110000 / 7
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Capacity: 31.44 GB (31,439,454,208 bytes)
  Removable Media:  Yes
  Detachable Drive: Yes
  BSD Name: disk4
  Partition Map Type:   MBR (Master Boot Record)
  S.M.A.R.T. status:    Not Supported
  Volumes:
CANON:
  Capacity: 31.44 GB (31,435,259,904 bytes)
  Available:    31.42 GB (31,421,562,880 bytes)
  Writable: No
  File System:  MS-DOS FAT32
  BSD Name: disk4s1
  Mount Point:  /Volumes/CANON
  Content:  Windows_FAT_32
  Volume UUID:  31F58768-8479-3FC8-8CA0-405944EBAC64
```

and here is what shows up for Camera 2 (the one that is not recognized by iPhoto or Image Capture):

```
Video Camera:

  Product ID:   0x326e
  Vendor ID:    0x04a9  (Canon Inc.)
  Version:  0.01
  Serial Number:    [redacted]
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: CANON Inc.
  Location ID:  0x1a120000 / 4
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Capacity: 31.44 GB (31,439,454,208 bytes)
  Removable Media:  Yes
  Detachable Drive: Yes
  BSD Name: disk4
  Partition Map Type:   MBR (Master Boot Record)
  S.M.A.R.T. status:    Not Supported
  Volumes:
CANON:
  Capacity: 31.44 GB (31,435,259,904 bytes)
  Available:    31.42 GB (31,423,430,656 bytes)
  Writable: No
  File System:  MS-DOS FAT32
  BSD Name: disk4s1
  Mount Point:  /Volumes/CANON
  Content:  Windows_FAT_32
  Volume UUID:  F1025F17-85DA-3580-845F-054D9A32D2A6
```

As you can see, the results are pretty much identical.

**Edited again:** Mystery solved!  I will post it as an answer below, for the benefit of anybody who ever has this (or a similar) problem.

Comment: Do the cameras have a setting for USB connection mode? If so, check that they both share the same settings such as "Mass Storage mode". That would explain why they are being treated differently. It may also be worth checking they both have the same firmware.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly There does not seem to be any setting related to USB connection mode. In any event they both appear as storage volumes on my desktop, which I think would not be the case if one of them were not set to Mass Storage mode.

Comment: Doesn't sound like that's it then. If the firmware is also identical on both I'd try resetting both cameras to factory defaults (if there's an option) and see if that makes them behave alike...

Comment: I thought of that, but I worried that it would make them both acquire the behavior I *don't* prefer!

Comment: You could try resetting just the one with the behaviour you *don't* like and see if that helps...

Comment: Are you using a memory card with either camera? Has the second camera ever appeared in iPhoto? Does the Image Capture application recognize it? When it's connected, go to Apple menu > About > System Report button. What does the USB bus report for the port where it is plugged in?

Comment: Both cameras have a memory card, but I have tried using the cameras with or without the card installed and the behavior is the same.  The second camera has never appeared in iPhoto.  I'll plug it in and see if I can answer your other questions.

Comment: Camera 1 (the one that shows up in iPhoto) also appears in Image Capture, but Camera 2 (which does now show up in iPhoto) does not appear in Image Capture.  So iPhoto and Image Capture are behaving in exactly the same way vis-a-vis the two cameras.

Comment: I will paste the USB bus info from System Report into the question.

Comment: Does each camera act the same no matter which cable you use, and no matter which USB port you use?

Comment: I'm using the same cable for both, and plugging them into the same port each time.

Comment: You may want to remove the serial numbers, just in case.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, @awesomebing1.  Done.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help -- mystery is solved (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved!  Behold the following two screenshots.  The first is from Camera 1:

[image]
and the second from Camera 2:

[image]

See the difference?  One of the cameras had a DCIM folder as a top-level directory (created, I can only assume, when I used that camera once to take a still photo) and the other did not.  Apparently the presence of that folder is what caused the OS to recognize it as a "device".

I just used Camera 2 to take a single photo, then connected it to my Mac.  It now has a DCIM folder, and iPhoto launched immediately.  That appears to have been it.